# node command does not work on beanstalk created with nodejs preconfiguration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an issue, I create a beanstalk with nodejs configuration and after it is in running status I ssh to the ec2 created by beanstalk. So my assumtion is that nodejs and npm are already installed in that ec2 but when I run

```
node --version
npm --version
```

I get the following errors:

```
-bash node:: command not found
-bash npm:: command not found
```

What am I missing here? Does this mean that I need to install node manually?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to setup nodejs.

Check the [documentation for how to setup the nodejs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-devenv.html) environment for beanstalk.

This is a complete guide on how to setup an Express app on [elastic beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html).

Comment: Even when I choose beanstalk with preconfig of nodejs?

Comment: Apparently yes.

Comment: Then what's the point of choosing Node JS Pre configured environment? I am just scratching my head